# Proof If $\langle S(v),v\rangle=0$ and S=S* so S=0

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for a simple proof that if $S$ a linear transformation $\langle S(v),v\rangle=0$ and $S=S^{*}$ so S is the zero transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Take two vectors $v$ and $w$ and expand
$$
0=\langle S(v+w),v+w\rangle=\langle S(v),v\rangle+\langle S(v),w\rangle+\langle S(w),v\rangle+\langle S(w),w\rangle. 
$$
By assumption, the first and last summand in the right hand side vanish, while the third summand can be rewritten as $\langle w,S^*(v)\rangle=\overline{\langle S(v),w\rangle}$. Hence you conclude that $\langle S(v),w\rangle$ has vanishing real part for all $v$ and $w$, which is only possible if $S(v)=0$ for all $v$.